# Add new element/attribute to both Parent and its child elements using single XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to add new elements and attributes to both Parent and its child elements using template copy and using one XSLT but am not able see the result I am expecting.

I am very new to XSLT and in the multiple templates only the template that matches to the root element is working. Other template matching the child element is not working.

Any help and techniques would be really helpful.

***Original XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <OrderLines Type="Text">
        <OrderLine Type="Fine Print">

        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

***Expected XML after XSLT transformation***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order>
    <Instructions>
        <Instruction InstructionType="Valid" InstructionText="See me" />
    </Instructions>
    <OrderLines Type="Text" Value="9">
        <OrderLine Type="Fine Print" Value="3">

        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/Order" />
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="/Order">
    <Order>
      <Instructions>
        <Instruction>
          <xsl:attribute name="InstructionType">
            <xsl:text>Valid</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="InstructionText">
            <xsl:text>See me</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </Instruction>
      </Instructions>
      <OrderLines>
        <xsl:attribute name="Type">
          <xsl:value-of select="OrderLines/@Type" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="Value">
          <xsl:value-of select="OrderLines/@Value" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <OrderLine>
          <xsl:attribute name="Type">
            <xsl:value-of select="OrderLines/OrderLine/@Type" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of select="OrderLines/OrderLine/@Value" />
          </xsl:attribute>
        </OrderLine>
      </OrderLines>
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't think this would work because the `Value` attributes don't exist in the input. Also, you should take a look at using AVTs for future stylesheets: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is start with the [identity transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) and then override it as needed. (This is normally referred to as the "push" style.)

Example...

**XML Input**

```
<Order>
    <OrderLines Type="Text">
        <OrderLine Type="Fine Print">

        </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines>
</Order>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!--Identity Transform-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Order">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Instructions>
                <Instruction InstructionType="Valid" InstructionText="See me" />
            </Instructions>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderLines">
        <OrderLines Value="9">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </OrderLines>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="OrderLine">
        <OrderLine Value="3">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </OrderLine>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<Order>
   <Instructions>
      <Instruction InstructionType="Valid" InstructionText="See me"/>
   </Instructions>
   <OrderLines Value="9" Type="Text">
      <OrderLine Value="3" Type="Fine Print"/>
   </OrderLines>
</Order>
```